# Table with INSERT statement conflict in totally different table

Tags: entity-framework

I am getting the following error.

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.NotificationObject_dbo.Comment_CommentReplyID". The conflict occurred in database "DB_f0f7b19b55c44199988352815f71b25c", table "dbo.Comment", column 'CommentID'.

I'm confused, because the `NotificationObject` table can have a wide variety of optional foreign keys, including a key to a comment, or a reply to a comment. When I try to add a row with a `CommentReplyID`, it gives the error above... about the comment table??? The key should point to the `CommentReply` table, so I'm pretty confused.

See the related models below.

```
public class NotificationObject
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int NotificationTypeID { get; set; }
    public int? CommentID { get; set; }
    public int? CommentVoteID { get; set; }
    public int? CommentReplyID { get; set; }
    public int? CommentReplyVoteID { get; set; }
    public int? UserID { get; set; }
    public int? ActivityCommentID { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    public virtual NotificationType NotificationType { get; set; }
    public virtual Comment Comment { get; set; }
    public virtual Comment CommentVote { get; set; }
    public virtual Comment CommentReply { get; set; }
    public virtual Comment CommentReplyVote { get; set; }
    public virtual ActivityComment ActivityComment { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<NotificationActor> NotificationActor { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
    public int CommentID { get; set; }
    public int ProjectDocID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public string quote { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CommentVote> CommentVote { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CommentReply> CommentReply { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CommentReport> CommentReport { get; set; }
    public virtual ProjectDoc ProjectDoc { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ranges> ranges { get; set; }
}
```

Why wont it let me add a value to the `CommentReplyID` field in the `NotificationObject` table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `CommentReply` navigation property in `NotificationObject` targets `Comment` type, not `CommentReply` type.

Comment: Btw. check other properties as well.

Comment: Yes, Just fixed all of those, heh. Whoops!